# Проблема с установкой python-ldap/django-auth-ldap

Tags: python, django, ldap

Столкнулся с проблемой при установке python-ldap/django-auth-ldap.Устанавливаю на Win10.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_SASL -DHAVE_TLS -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DLDAPMODULE_VERSION=3.3.1 "-DLDAPMODULE_AUTHOR=python-ldap project" "-DLDAPMODULE_LICENSE=Python style" -IModules -Ic:\users...\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include -Ic:\users...\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" /TcModules/LDAPObject.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\Modules/LDAPObject.obj
LDAPObject.c
c:\users...\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include\pyconfig.h(205): fatal error C1083: ЌҐ г¤ Ґвбп ®вЄалвм д ©« ўЄ«озҐ­ЁҐ: basetsd.h: No such file or directory,
error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я пытаюсь установить библиотеку django-auth-ldap, в процессе установки появляется сообщение об ошибки: fatal error C1083: Не удается открыть файл включение: basetsd.h: No such file or directory,